# jCanvas image drawing on Node

Tags: jquery, node.js, jsdom, jcanvas, node-canvas

So I am on Windows and I have followed the example for running jCanvas on Node: https://github.com/robertjustjones/jcanvas-in-node

And I can get the example to work, however I have problems when I try to use jCanvas's draw image capabilities such as:

```
$c.drawImage({
  source: 'images/fish.jpg',
  x: 50, y: 50,
  width: 80,
  height: 100,
  fromCenter: false
});
```

The problem I have is I get returned some data: base 64 encoding of just a blank canvas.

Even stranger, when running Node on Linux I simply get `undefined` returned from:

```
console.log($c.getCanvasImage('png'));
```